# Como reduzir espaço entre bullet e texto numa <ul> centralizada?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma lista centralizada.

```html
<ul style="text-align: center; list-style-position: inside;">
    <li>abc</li>    
    <li>xyz</li> 
</ul>
```

A questão é que o bullet fica muito longe do texto. Gostaria que ficasse bem próximo. Já tentei `padding` e `margin` no style do `ul` e do `li`. Mas nenhum funcionou.

Comment: experimenta isto: `<li><span>abc</span><li>` e no css faça `ul li { position:relative; left:-5px; }`

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Você testou essa solução? Para mim não funcionou. Ou eu que estou fazendo errado.
    <ul style="text-align: center; list-style-position: inside;">
          <li style="position:relative; left:-5px;"><span>abc</span></li>  
    </ul>

Comment: não aplique os estilos dentro da tag `li` ou `ul`, coloque-os numa tag `style` ou num arquivo `css`.

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução seria envolver o conteúdo dos LIs em uma tag e posicioná-la para a esquerda.

```css
li span { position: relative; left: -30px; }
```

```html
<ul style="text-align: center; list-style-position: inside;">
    <li><span>abc</span></li>    
    <li><span>xyz</span></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: funcionou! Muitissimo obrigado. Votei um +1 pra você mas como sou usuário novo, o meu voto não fica visível foi a resposta que recebi do sistema.

Comment: agora notei que têm variação de browser pra browser. Colocando -5px no firefox fica bom, mas no chrome fica super distante.

Answer (score -1):

Eu receio que a única solução seja você fazer manualmente:

```
    ul {
    list-style-type: none; /*Remove o bullet*/
}

li {
background-position: 0px 50%;
    background-image: url(bullet.jpg); /*adiciona uma imagem*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    padding-left: 7px;
}
```

Veja se isso funciona.

referências:

http://www.escolaw3.com/tutoriais/css/listas